# In Java, while debugging, how can I search all objects in heap for text

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, java-11, oql

I am trying to find a hidden piece of data inside some large maps in a Java program. It would be very easy if I could (in a way) "`sed`" or "`grep`" through all the objects in the heap and determine where a specific line of ASCII text exists.

Can this be done with Java code or with an IDE? I know it can be done in small ways by dumping variables into a log, but I'd rather not blow up my logs this way. Is there a way to run a search query on all my objects?

Comment: In Eclipse, you can specify a [_Detail Formatter_](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/debug/ref-detail_formatters.htm) to show only the map entries containing a specific text in the _Variables_ view. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Searching all objects of the heap would require taking a heap dump. When you search for java heap dump analysis programs, you will find some. VisualVM, for example, supports querying the heap dump using OQL scripts.